# Add strings from the bans history page into transifex

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/review/bans

> [image: Bans history page]

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/review/bans/historical

> [image: Bans history]